# Tomcat's Catalina Logs from ECS Fargate to Cloudwatch

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am deploying spring boot application in Tomcat container which runs on ECS Fargate.

Docker Image I am using is "tomcat:9.0.65-jdk11" types. So Log file will be catalina-{date1}.log

I need to setup a logging in Cloudwatch. Currently the log driver can send only IO logs to Cloudwatch. But I need to send catalina-{date1}.log, catalina-[date2].log... to Cloudwatch.

I have also tried with AWS Firelens and Fluent Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Tomcat to send those logs to STDOUT/STDERR instead of, or in addition to, the log files. ECS will automatically send the output of the primary process's STDOUT/STDERR to CloudWatch Logs.

Basically you should configure the Tomcat container such that when you run the container locally, the logs you want to see show up in the docker console output.

Comment: i want to revive this question above.. i understand the tomcat logs can be configured to stdout/stderr then cloudwatch can monitor.. this is the easy solution. however if i want to monitor not just catalina logs.. i want to monitor access logs as well as application logs... so each log usually is logged in a separate file/stream.. and i want to monitor them separately it doesn't make sense to send all the logs into the stdout/stderr... what is the best/easiest way to do that..?

Comment: @wkt Instead of reviving a question, just ask your own, separate question on here please. I think you would have to run a sidecar container to manage the log streams like you want, but I'm not going to write up a detailed answer for that in comments.